# (Redux typscript react) type initial store has no properties in common with type store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

Hello i've been struggling with this for a while

i want to start with a initial state like so:

```
const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: {}}
};
```

but i already have a couple reducers that make my initial state like so:

```
{
productList?:undefined,
productDetails?:undefined
}
```

but i get the error:

```
 Type '{cart:{cartItems:{}}' has no properties in common with type '{productList?: undefined, productDetails? :undefined}'
```

my reducer looks like:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] as any[] }, action:productListReducer) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        products: [] as any[],
      };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
      };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,

});
```

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Where’s your cart reducer?  Your initial state can be incomplete, but it’s giving you an error because there is no cart property on the reducer.

Comment: I didn't create a reducer for the cart yet i just want to start with that initial state without having a reducer, do you need to create one just to start with a initial state in the store? pd added more details of my code.